# Upgrade 14.4 to 16.04 - An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade

Tags: 14.04, apt, upgrade

Im trying to upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04 but get the following error -

```
Calculating the changes

Calculating the changes

Could not calculate the upgrade 

An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade.
```

I checked the apt.log but there are tons of error. Not sure how to remove everything -

```
Broken libpcl-io-1.7-dev:amd64 Depends on libpcl-io-1.7 [ amd64 ] < 1.7.1-3+trusty3 > ( libs ) (= 1.7.1-3+trusty3)
Broken libpcl-io-1.7:amd64 Depends on libvtk5.8 [ amd64 ] < 5.8.0-14.1ubuntu3 > ( libs )
Broken libpcl-visualization-1.7-dev:amd64 Depends on libpcl-visualization-1.7 [ amd64 ] < 1.7.1-3+trusty3 > ( libs ) (= 1.7.1-3+trusty3)
Broken libpcl-1.7-all-dev:amd64 Depends on libpcl-visualization-1.7-dev [ amd64 ] < 1.7.1-3+trusty3 > ( libdevel )
Broken libpcl-surface-1.7-dev:amd64 Depends on libpcl-surface-1.7 [ amd64 ] < 1.7.1-3+trusty3 > ( libs ) (= 1.7.1-3+trusty3)
Broken libpcl-people-1.7-dev:amd64 Depends on libpcl-visualization-1.7-dev [ amd64 ] < 1.7.1-3+trusty3 > ( libdevel )
Broken libpcl-outofcore-1.7-dev:amd64 Depends on libpcl-visualization-1.7-dev [ amd64 ] < 1.7.1-3+trusty3 > ( libdevel )
Broken libpcl-apps-1.7-dev:amd64 Depends on libpcl-apps-1.7 [ amd64 ] < 1.7.1-3+trusty3 > ( libs ) (= 1.7.1-3+trusty3)
Broken libparse-debianchangelog-perl:amd64 Depends on libcgi-pm-perl [ amd64 ] < none -> 4.26-1 > ( perl )
Broken libparse-debianchangelog-perl:amd64 Depends on perl [ amd64 ] < 5.18.2-2ubuntu1.1 -> 5.22.1-9 > ( perl ) (< 5.19)
Broken libcegui-mk2-dev:amd64 Depends on libcegui-mk2-0.7.6 [ amd64 ] < 0.7.6-2ubuntu4 > ( libs ) (= 0.7.6-2ubuntu4)
Broken ros-indigo-rqt-common-plugins:amd64 Depends on ros-indigo-rqt-image-view [ amd64 ] < 0.4.8-0trusty-20170428-112649-0800 > ( misc )
Broken ros-indigo-rqt-robot-plugins:amd64 Depends on ros-indigo-rqt-rviz [ amd64 ] < 0.5.7-0trusty-20170605-172631-0800 > ( misc )
Broken python3.4:amd64 Depends on python3.4-minimal [ amd64 ] < 3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.5 > ( python ) (= 3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.5)
Broken ros-indigo-collada-urdf:amd64 Depends on libassimp3 [ amd64 ] < 3.0~dfsg-2 > ( libs ) (>= 3.0~)
Broken ros-indigo-robot-model:amd64 Depends on ros-indigo-collada-urdf [ amd64 ] < 1.11.14-0trusty-20170504-082818-0800 > ( misc )
Broken libvtk5.8:amd64 Depends on libopenmpi1.6 [ amd64 ] < 1.6.5-8 > ( libs )
Broken ros-indigo-robot:amd64 Depends on ros-indigo-robot-model [ amd64 ] < 1.11.13-0trusty-20170517-151002-0800 > ( misc )
Broken libopenmpi1.10:amd64 Conflicts on libopenmpi1.6 [ amd64 ] < 1.6.5-8 > ( libs )
Broken libvtk5.10:amd64 Depends on libopenmpi1.10 [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.10.2-8ubuntu1 > ( universe/libs )
Broken openmpi-bin:amd64 Depends on libopenmpi1.10 [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.10.2-8ubuntu1 > ( universe/libs )
Broken tcl-vtk:amd64 Depends on libvtk5.10 [ amd64 ] < none -> 5.10.1+dfsg-2.1build1 > ( universe/libs ) (= 5.10.1+dfsg-2.1build1)
Broken libopenmpi-dev:amd64 Depends on libopenmpi1.10 [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.10.2-8ubuntu1 > ( universe/libs ) (= 1.10.2-8ubuntu1)
Broken python-vtk:amd64 Depends on libopenmpi1.10 [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.10.2-8ubuntu1 > ( universe/libs )
Broken mpi-default-bin:amd64 Depends on openmpi-bin [ amd64 ] < 1.6.5-8 -> 1.10.2-8ubuntu1 > ( universe/net )
Broken libboost-mpi1.58.0:amd64 Depends on libopenmpi1.10 [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.10.2-8ubuntu1 > ( universe/libs )
Broken libvtk-java:amd64 Depends on libvtk5.10 [ amd64 ] < none -> 5.10.1+dfsg-2.1build1 > ( universe/libs )
Broken libboost-mpi1.58-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost-mpi1.58.0 [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1 > ( universe/libs ) (= 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1)
Broken libvtk5.10-qt4:amd64 Depends on libvtk5.10 [ amd64 ] < none -> 5.10.1+dfsg-2.1build1 > ( universe/libs )
Broken libboost-mpi-python1.58.0:amd64 Depends on libboost-mpi1.58.0 [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1 > ( universe/libs )
Broken libboost-graph-parallel1.58.0:amd64 Depends on libboost-mpi1.58.0 [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1 > ( universe/libs )
Broken libboost-mpi-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost-mpi1.58-dev [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1 > ( universe/libdevel )
Broken libvtk5-dev:amd64 Depends on libvtk5.10 [ amd64 ] < none -> 5.10.1+dfsg-2.1build1 > ( universe/libs ) (= 5.10.1+dfsg-2.1build1)
Broken mpi-default-dev:amd64 Depends on libopenmpi-dev [ amd64 ] < 1.6.5-8 -> 1.10.2-8ubuntu1 > ( universe/libdevel )
Broken libvtk5-qt4-dev:amd64 Depends on libvtk5-dev [ amd64 ] < 5.8.0-14.1ubuntu3 -> 5.10.1+dfsg-2.1build1 > ( universe/libdevel ) (= 5.10.1+dfsg-2.1build1)
Broken libboost-graph-parallel1.58-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost-graph-parallel1.58.0 [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1 > ( universe/libs ) (= 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1)
Broken libboost-mpi-python1.58-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost-mpi1.58-dev [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1 > ( universe/libdevel ) (= 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1)
Broken libboost-all-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost-mpi-dev [ amd64 ] < 1.54.0.1ubuntu1 -> 1.58.0.1ubuntu1 > ( universe/libdevel )
Broken libboost-mpi-python-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost-mpi-python1.58-dev [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1 > ( universe/libdevel )
Broken libboost-mpi-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost-mpi1.54-dev [ amd64 ] < 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 > ( libdevel )
Broken libboost-graph-parallel-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost-graph-parallel1.58-dev [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1 > ( universe/libdevel )
Broken libvtk5-dev:amd64 Depends on mpi-default-dev [ amd64 ] < 1.0.2ubuntu1 -> 1.4 > ( universe/libdevel )
Broken mpi-default-dev:amd64 Depends on libopenmpi-dev [ amd64 ] < 1.6.5-8 -> 1.10.2-8ubuntu1 > ( universe/libdevel )
Broken libopenmpi-dev:amd64 Depends on openmpi-common [ amd64 ] < 1.6.5-8 -> 1.10.2-8ubuntu1 > ( universe/net ) (= 1.6.5-8)
Broken libboost-mpi1.54-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost1.54-dev [ amd64 ] < 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 > ( libdevel ) (= 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1)
Broken libboost-mpi1.54-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost-serialization1.54-dev [ amd64 ] < 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 > ( libdevel ) (= 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1)
Broken libboost-mpi1.54-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost-mpi1.54.0 [ amd64 ] < 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 > ( libs ) (= 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1)
Broken libboost-all-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost-graph-parallel-dev [ amd64 ] < 1.54.0.1ubuntu1 -> 1.58.0.1ubuntu1 > ( universe/libdevel )
Broken libboost-all-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost-mpi-python-dev [ amd64 ] < 1.54.0.1ubuntu1 -> 1.58.0.1ubuntu1 > ( universe/libdevel )
Broken libboost-mpi-python-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost-mpi-python1.54-dev [ amd64 ] < 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 > ( libdevel )
Broken libboost-graph-parallel-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost-graph-parallel1.54-dev [ amd64 ] < 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 > ( libdevel )
Broken libboost1.58-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libboost1.54-dev [ amd64 ] < 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 > ( libdevel )
Broken libboost-python1.58-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost1.58-dev [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1 > ( libdevel ) (= 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1)
Broken libboost-test1.58-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost1.58-dev [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1 > ( libdevel ) (= 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1)
Broken libboost-wave1.58-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost1.58-dev [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1 > ( libdevel ) (= 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1)
Broken libboost-coroutine1.58-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost1.58-dev [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1 > ( libdevel ) (= 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1)
Broken libboost-serialization1.58-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost1.58-dev [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1 > ( libdevel ) (= 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1)
Broken libboost-timer1.58-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost1.58-dev [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1 > ( libdevel ) (= 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1)
Broken libboost-log1.58-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost1.58-dev [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1 > ( libdevel ) (= 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1)
Broken libboost-chrono1.58-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost1.58-dev [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1 > ( libdevel ) (= 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1)
Broken libboost-math1.58-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost1.58-dev [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1 > ( libdevel ) (= 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1)
Broken libboost-signals1.58-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost1.58-dev [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1 > ( libdevel ) (= 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1)
Broken libboost-context1.58-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost1.58-dev [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1 > ( libdevel ) (= 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1)
Broken libboost-random1.58-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost1.58-dev [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1 > ( libdevel ) (= 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1)
Broken libboost-atomic1.58-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost1.58-dev [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1 > ( libdevel ) (= 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1)
Broken libboost-exception1.58-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost1.58-dev [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1 > ( libdevel ) (= 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1)
Broken libboost-graph1.58-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost1.58-dev [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1 > ( libdevel ) (= 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1)
Broken libboost-locale1.58-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost1.58-dev [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1 > ( libdevel ) (= 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1)
Broken libboost-mpi-python1.54-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost-mpi-python1.54.0 [ amd64 ] < 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 > ( python ) (= 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1)
Broken libboost-graph-parallel1.54-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost-graph-parallel1.54.0 [ amd64 ] < 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 > ( libs ) (= 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1)
Broken libboost-graph-parallel1.54-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost-test1.54-dev [ amd64 ] < 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 > ( libdevel ) (= 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1)
Broken libboost-mpi-python1.54.0:amd64 Depends on mpi-default-bin [ amd64 ] < 1.0.2ubuntu1 -> 1.4 > ( universe/net )
Broken libboost-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost1.58-dev [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1 > ( libdevel )
Broken libboost-timer-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost-timer1.58-dev [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1 > ( universe/libdevel )
Broken libboost-coroutine-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost-coroutine1.58-dev [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1 > ( universe/libdevel )
Broken libboost-wave-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost-wave1.58-dev [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1 > ( universe/libdevel )
Broken libboost-test-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost-test1.58-dev [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1 > ( universe/libdevel )
Broken libboost-context-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost-context1.58-dev [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1 > ( universe/libdevel )
Broken libboost-python-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost-python1.58-dev [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1 > ( universe/libdevel )
Broken libboost-random-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost-random1.58-dev [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1 > ( universe/libdevel )
Broken libboost-log-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost-log1.58-dev [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1 > ( universe/libdevel )
Broken libboost-chrono-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost-chrono1.58-dev [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1 > ( universe/libdevel )
Broken libboost-signals-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost-signals1.58-dev [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1 > ( universe/libdevel )
Broken libboost-graph-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost-graph1.58-dev [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1 > ( universe/libdevel )
Broken libboost-math-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost-math1.58-dev [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1 > ( universe/libdevel )
Broken libboost-atomic-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost-atomic1.58-dev [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1 > ( universe/libdevel )
Broken libboost-exception-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost-exception1.58-dev [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1 > ( universe/libdevel )
Broken libboost-serialization-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost-serialization1.58-dev [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1 > ( universe/libdevel )
Broken libboost-locale-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost-locale1.58-dev [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1 > ( universe/libdevel )
Broken libboost-system1.58-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost1.58-dev [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1 > ( libdevel ) (= 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1)
Broken libboost-filesystem1.58-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost1.58-dev [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1 > ( libdevel ) (= 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1)
Broken libboost-regex1.58-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost1.58-dev [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1 > ( libdevel ) (= 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1)
Broken libboost-date-time1.58-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost1.58-dev [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1 > ( libdevel ) (= 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1)
Broken libboost-iostreams1.58-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost1.58-dev [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1 > ( libdevel ) (= 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1)
Broken libboost-program-options1.58-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost1.58-dev [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1 > ( libdevel ) (= 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1)
Broken libboost-thread1.58-dev:amd64 Depends on libboost1.58-dev [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1 > ( libdevel ) (= 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1)
Broken mpi-default-bin:amd64 Depends on openmpi-bin [ amd64 ] < 1.6.5-8 -> 1.10.2-8ubuntu1 > ( universe/net )
```

Comment: Is it now 16.04?

Comment: 14.04 current version

Comment: Try `sudo apt install -f`

Comment: If the above doesn't work you should seriously consider a fresh installation.